# Only able to access first record in a query

Tags: google-app-maker

(server side script)

This is a stripped down version of my code but what this should be doing is

- find records where the "uniqueid" is equal to matchid
- return 0 if there are less than two of these items
- print the region of each item if there are two or more items
- return the number of items

  ```
  function copyFile(matchid){

    var fileName = getProp('projectName')+" "+row[0];
    var query = app.models.Files.newQuery();

    query.filters.uniqueid._equals = matchid;
    records = query.run();
    var len = records.length;
    if (len < 2) return 0;
    console.log(row[2]+"  - "+len);          

    for (var i=0; i<len;i++){            
      console.log("Loop "+i);
      var r = records[i];
      console.log(r.region);
    }
    return records.length
  ```

Strangely, it can only get at the region (or any of the other data for the FIRST record ( records[0]) for the others it says undefined. This is extremely confusing and frustrating. To reiterate it passes the len < 2 check, so there are more records in the set returned from the query, they just seem to be undefined if I try to get them from records[i]

Note: uniqueid is not actually a unique field, the name is from something else, sorry about confusion.

Question: WHY can't I get at records[1] records [2]

Answer (score 0):

This was a ridiculous problem and I don't entirely understand the solution.

Changing "records" to "recs" entirely fixes my problem.

why does records[0] work, records[1] does not

but recs[0] and recs[1] both work.

I believe "records" has a special meaning and points at something regardless of assignment in this context.